# Recursive function: Syracuse

Tags: python, recursion

I want to print a list of the syracuse sequence. 
My recursive function only gives back [1]

### I know the syracuse_sequence in syracuse(n) is a local variable, but I don't know how to return the list.

```
import sys

def syracuse(n):
        syracuse_sequence = []
        if n == 1:
                syracuse_sequence.append(round(n))
                print(syracuse_sequence)
                return 0
        elif n % 2 == 0:
                n /= 2
                syracuse_sequence.append(round(n))
                return 1 + syracuse(n)
        else:
                n = (n * 3 ) + 1
                syracuse_sequence.append(round(n))
                return 1 + syracuse(n)

def main(argv):
        n = int(argv[1])
        syracuse(n)
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main(sys.argv)
```

---

The result I expect is:

```
$python3 syracuse.py 17
[17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: You create a new list for each invocation of the function. You should pass the list in, and return it. Rather than using `n` to calculate the next number, use the last number from the list.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The thing is that it does not allow me the return a list, because the parameter of the function is (n). So when I:   "return syracuse_sequence"  its mentions that is is not able to return a list.

Comment: N.B. that the arguments to a function have no bearing on what it can return. In Python a function can even return two or more different types (`return (True if n%2==0 else [1,2,3,4,5])`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this recursively. One is to make the accumulator an argument to the recursive function.

```
def syracuse(n, acc=None):
    if acc is None:
        acc = []  # why do this? Search "mutable default arguments"
                  # and the side effects that come with!
    if n == 1:
        acc.append(n)
        return acc
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        n /= 2
        acc.append(n)
        return syracuse(n, acc)
    else:
        n = (n*3) + 1
        acc.append(n)
        return syracuse(n, acc)
```

The other way is to embed the accumulator in each function call.

```
def syracuse(n):
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n % 2:
        return [n] + syracuse(n/2)
    else:
        return [n] + syracuse(n*3+1)
```

This works because `[1] + [2] + [3, 4, 5] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Since each call to `syracuse` produces another list to be added with the previous, we get:

```
syracuse(5) =
[5] + syracuse(16) =
[5] + [16] + syracuse(8) =
[5] + [16] + [8] + syracuse(4) =
[5] + [16] + [8] + [4] = syracuse(2) =
[5] + [16] + [8] + [4] + [2] + syracuse(1) =
[5] + [16] + [8] + [4] + [2] + [1] =
[5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```

---

Do note, however, that recursion is something Python does particularly poorly. You should greatly prefer iteration here.

Comment: For an example of each of these in action in a language that is uses recursion for *everything*, see [this example in haskell](https://repl.it/repls/AttachedPerkyMidge) where `syracuse'` is the first example here and `syracuse` is the second.

Comment: Python doesn't do recursion any more poorly than it does any other function call. It just artificially caps the size of the call stack (something which can grow too large even in the absence of recursion, although it would take a lot of effort) to avoid a runaway recursive function from consuming too much memory before ultimately crashing.

Comment: @chepner right, but function calls are generally more expensive in Python (which is why iterative solutions are cheaper in Python) and CPython at least doesn't do tail call elimination unlike many other languages.

Comment: @chepner my point was that recursion is in general a poor choice in Python both because Iterative Python is faster than Recursive Python, and because Recursive Python is slower than Recursive (many other popular languages)

Comment: No argument there; iteration is preferred, but recursion isn't really the problem; excessive function calls (which recursion is especially prone to producing) are.

Comment: @chepner Po-tay-to po-tah-to ;)

Comment: @Adam Smith Thank you for your explanation. I will look into "mutable default arguments", because I see that it works but I want to understand why. 
I am a little overwhelmed by all the quick replies. 
Again thank you for helping me!

Comment: @y.j.r the mutable default arguments note is more for further reading on why I did `syracuse(n, acc=None)` instead of `...acc=[])` when I only change that `None` to an empty list later. It doesn't factor into the mechanics of the answer, but only works around a common "gotcha" in Python

Comment: @Adam Smith Yes I definitely will look into it further.  I am eager to learn more, so thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You want a loop:

```
import sys

def syracuse(n):
    syracuse_sequence = [n]
    while True:
        if n == 1:
            print(syracuse_sequence)
            return 0
        elif n % 2 == 0:
            n /= 2
            syracuse_sequence.append(round(n))
            continue
        else:
            n = (n * 3 ) + 1
            syracuse_sequence.append(round(n))
            continue

def main(argv):
    n = int(argv[1])
    syracuse(n)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

This will run the program until it gets to 1 (which I assume is what you want)

This is what it outputs for 17:

[image: Output from 17]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your solution and time. Although with recursion you are not allowed to use while. The function itself should loop until: " n == 1" and then give back the list "syracuse_sequence".

Comment: @y.j.r That is exactly what it does, I intentionally didn't use recursion (this program does NOT recurse) as that isnt the most efficient solution and you would soon run into errors with MAXRECURSIONDEPTH. If you want to try it out, copy the code and run it. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I agree, but I need to this for an assignment.

Comment: @y.j.r Oh ok, I'll post a separate answer then. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with recursion is passing and returning the list, rather than `n`. `n` is then just the last element of the list. This reuses the same list object throughout the recursion, rather than creating new ones constantly, so has memory and performance advantages over e.g. Adam Smith's second version.

```
def syracuse(seq):
    n = seq[-1]
    if n == 1:            # done
        return seq
    if n % 2:             # odd
        seq.append(n * 3 + 1)
        return syracuse(seq)
    seq.append(n // 2)    # even
    return syracuse(seq)
```

I have also removed a few things you don't need in your code and rearranged it a bit to simplify it.

To call it, you must pass `n` as a single-item list:

```
syracuse([17])
```

If you don't want to have to pass in a list, just add a test to the beginning:

```
def syracuse(seq):
    if type(seq) is not list:
       seq = [seq]
    n = seq[-1]
    if n == 1:            # done
        return seq
    if n % 2:             # odd
        seq.append(n * 3 + 1)
        return syracuse(seq)
    seq.append(n // 2)    # even
    return syracuse(seq)
```

Or add a helper function:

```
def syracuse2(seq):
    n = seq[-1]
    if n == 1:            # done
        return seq
    if n % 2:             # odd
        seq.append(n * 3 + 1)
        return syracuse2(seq)
    seq.append(n // 2)    # even
    return syracuse2(seq)

def syracuse(n):
    return syracuse2([n])
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions. I appreciate the time and effort you put into this.